# Setting Cron job with whenever gem in AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cron, whenever

I am trying to set a cron job with the help of [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) in my Opswork Ruby on Rails App.

I have found [these instructions](https://github.com/StemboltHQ/frt-opsworks-cookbooks/tree/master/whenever) as a whenever recipe, but since I don't know much about Chef I am a little bit lost.

The suggested code:

```
Just include whenever in your node's run_list:

{
  "name":"my_node",
"run_list": [
"recipe[whenever]"
]
}
```

I was adding it in the layer settings as a custom JSON but I get an error when I try to deploy:

```
ERROR: please set the node's run list using the 'run_list' attribute only.
```

I'm defining my cron job as follows:

```
#config/schedule.rb
env :PATH, '/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/opt/aws/bin'

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "UserMailer.mailgun.deliver"
end
```

I have added `whenever::deploy` to my recipes under the layer settings as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18058996/3307520) and the `update cookbooks` command was successful, but when I tried to deploy I had an error stating `whenever` recipe was not found

How should I set whenever or the cronjob in order to run in AWS?

Comment: this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21125575/3307520

Comment: @Cyzanfar I added the cookbook to the stack setting (https://github.com/StemboltHQ/frt-opsworks-cookbooks/tree/master/whenever) and added the recipe to the layer setting in the deploy section, but I get ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"  no such cookbook whenever

Comment: Myabe your directory setup is wrong take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18058996/3307520

Comment: @Cyzanfar I added whenever::deploy to my cookbooks as suggested in that link and when I ran updated cookbooks it was successful, but when I tried to deploy it said whenever cookbook not found